# .htaccess RewriteRule 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect image files to a diferente folder. I tried using:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ images/$1    [L]
```

This results in a 500 Internal Server Error, but the following works:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)
    RewriteRule ^(media/1.jpg)$ images/$1   [L]
```

This also works:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ images/media/1.jpg   [L]
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting 500 error because of looping. Apache keeps running rewritten URIs with `mod_rewrite` module until they fail to match any rule.

Try this rule with better checks:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ images%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This will rewrite image URLs only when `/images/` is not present in URI.